# RPM issue "Build executing returned '139'"

Tags: java, maven, rpm

I am running into the following error below. This error is only occurring on my machine and others have no problem running this. I setup RPM threw brew just like the others running this and have tried uninstalling and reinstalling it. Has anyone ran into this issue before?

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:rpm-maven-plugin:2.1.2:rpm (default) on project domains-rg-listeners-core: RPM build execution returned: '139' executing '/bin/sh -c cd '/Users/bcampbell/Documents/godaddy/domains-rg-api/listeners/core/target/rpm/domains-rg-listeners-core-7b2e1/SPECS' && 'rpmbuild' '-bb' '--target' 'noarch-apple-linux' '--buildroot' '/Users/bcampbell/Documents/godaddy/domains-rg-api/listeners/core/target/rpm/domains-rg-listeners-core-7b2e1/buildroot' '--define' '_topdir /Users/bcampbell/Documents/godaddy/domains-rg-api/listeners/core/target/rpm/domains-rg-listeners-core-7b2e1' 'domains-rg-listeners-core-7b2e1.spec'' -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:rpm-maven-plugin:2.1.2:rpm (default) on project domains-rg-listeners-core: RPM build execution returned: '139' executing '/bin/sh -c cd '/Users/bcampbell/Documents/godaddy/domains-rg-api/listeners/core/target/rpm/domains-rg-listeners-core-7b2e1/SPECS' && 'rpmbuild' '-bb' '--target' 'noarch-apple-linux' '--buildroot' '/Users/bcampbell/Documents/godaddy/domains-rg-api/listeners/core/target/rpm/domains-rg-listeners-core-7b2e1/buildroot' '--define' '_topdir /Users/bcampbell/Documents/godaddy/domains-rg-api/listeners/core/target/rpm/domains-rg-listeners-core-7b2e1' 'domains-rg-listeners-core-7b2e1.spec''
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)

Comment: Is the output from the command stored anywhere? That looks like it might be the spec file itself failing.

Comment: Not sure why you put a "java" tag on this one ...